# Alphabetic order regex using backreferences

Tags: regex, backreference, character-class

I recently came across a puzzle to find a regular expression that matches:

> 5-character-long strings comprised of lowercase English letters in ascending ASCII order

Valid examples include:

```
aaaaa
abcde
xxyyz
ghost
chips
demos
```

Invalid examples include:

```
abCde
xxyyzz
hgost
chps
```

My current solution is kludgy. I use the regex:

```
(?=^[a-z]{5}$)^(a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*)$
```

which uses a non-consuming capture group to assert a string length of 5, and then verifies that the string comprises of lowercase English letters in order ([see Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/frCRCvxR48)).

Instead, I'd like to use back references inside character classes. Something like:

```
^([a-z])([\1-z])([\2-z])([\3-z])([\4-z])$
```

The logic for the solution ([see Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/HofzzSze18)) in my head is to capture the first character [a-z], use it as a backrefence in the second character class and so on. However, `\1`, `\2` ... within character classes seem to refer to ASCII values of 1, 2... effectively matching any four- or five-character string.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I use back references in my character classes to check for ascending order strings?
2. Is there any less-hacky solution to this puzzle?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your kludgy solution is as sweet as it gets because the character classes don't play nice with your backreferences (but I do like your logic, seems like a nice feature to have).  Do you have a specific environment to run this regex in (Ruby only or agnostic)?  I am sure the regex wizards of SO will be along shortly to add their expertise.

Comment: Uh, no backreferences inside character classes. The reason is that character classes are composed at _compile time_. The determining factor is that a backreference is dynamic, and what disqualifies it inside a class is the range operator. So, they say.. _No dynamic range_ elst the engine crashes in a C++ exception.

Comment: `came across a puzzle to find a regular expression` - Be sure to _cite_ that link so we may laugh at the puzzler..

Comment: Actually, it's quite easy in a Perl regex. You can do all sorts of stuff, like counting, sequences, bools, subtraction, etc... `(?{..})`. If you think you'd use Perl, then it's .. doable. Btw, your first regex is just fine.

Comment: One other thing to note is that in character classes the _range_ operator pertains to single characters (min,max) not a set of characters, like `\pL-z` throws a construction error. In that vein, a reference can contain multiple characters.

Comment: Why is `demos` included in invalid list?

Comment: ok, your regex looks pretty nice to me. You can slightly improve it by using: `^(?=[a-z]{5}$)a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$`

Comment: duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171671/regex-5-digits-in-increasing-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171671/regex-5-digits-in-increasing-order)

Comment: Question cannot be closed due to bounty, but that is a dead-on dupe link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this answer more as a comment than an answer since it has better formatting than comments.

Related to your questions:

> 1. Can I use back references in my character classes to check for ascending order strings?

No, you can't. If you take a look a [backref regular-expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) section, you will find below documentation:

> **Parentheses and Backreferences Cannot Be Used Inside Character Classes**
>
> Parentheses cannot be used inside character classes, at least not as metacharacters. When you put a parenthesis in a character class, it is treated as a literal character. So the regex [(a)b] matches a, b, (, and ).
>
> **Backreferences, too, cannot be used inside a character class**. The \1 in a regex like (a)[\1b] is either an **error or a needlessly escaped literal 1**. In JavaScript it's an octal escape.

Regarding your 2nd question:

> 2. Is there any less-hacky solution to this puzzle?

Imho, your regex is perfectly well, you could shorten it very little at the beginning like this:

```
(?=^.{5}$)^a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n*o*p*q*r*s*t*u*v*w*x*y*z*$
    ^--- Here
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j1zq6C/1)**

Comment: I think it's worth saying *why* backreferences in character classes are not possible. A backreference can point to a matched substring, which could be any length, even empty. Thus, code like `[\1-z]` could yield `[-z]`, `[f-z]`, `[foo-z]` etc. That doesn't make much sense and the pattern would have to be recompiled on the fly, preventing optimizations.

Comment: It's disturbing to see doc's quoted when they don't provide reasons for if something can't be used in such a fundamental way. References inside character classes is such an example. But, you could always use your own reasoning for such a case, and it's fairly easy to know why in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use Perl (!), this will work:

```
/^([a-z])((??{"[$1-z]"}))((??{"[$2-z]"}))((??{"[$3-z]"}))(??{"[$4-z]"})$/
```

Comment: But... that's cheating! :) If you use Perl then I guess you could just code the assertion directly: `/^([a-z]{5})$(?(?{$1 eq (join "", sort split qr##, $1)})|(?!))/`

Comment: At some point I think it is questionable as to whether you are doing a Regex solution. I think mine is closer on the continuum :)

Answer (score 2):

Since someone has broken the ice by using Perl, this is a
Perl solution I guess ..

---

*Note that this is a basic non-regex solution that just happens to be

stuffed into code constructs inside a Perl regex.

The interesting thing is that if a day comes when you need the synergy

of regex/code this is a good choice.

It is possible then that instead of a simple `[a-z]` character, you may

use a very complex pattern in it's place and using a check vs. last.

That is power !!*

---

The regex `^(?:([a-z])(?(?{ $last gt $1 })(?!)|(?{ $last = $1 }))){5}$`

Perl code

```
use strict;
use warnings;


$/ = "";

my @DAry = split /\s+/, <DATA>;

my $last;

for (@DAry)
{
    $last = '';
    if ( 
      /
         ^                             # BOS
         (?:                           # Cluster begin
              ( [a-z] )                     # (1), Single a-z letter
                                            # Code conditional
              (?(?{
                   $last gt $1                  # last > current ?
                })
                   (?!)                          # Fail
                |                              # else,
                   (?{ $last = $1 })             # Assign last = current
              )
         ){5}                          # Cluster end, do 5 times
         $                             # EOS
      /x )
    {
        print "good   $_\n";
    }
    else {
        print "bad    $_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__

aaaaa
abcde
xxyyz
ghost
chips
demos
abCde
xxyyzz
hgost
chps
```

Output

```
good   aaaaa
good   abcde
good   xxyyz
good   ghost
good   chips
good   demos
bad    abCde
bad    xxyyzz
bad    hgost
bad    chps
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, well, it's a finite set, so you can always enumerate it with alternation! This emits a "brute force" kind of regex in a little perl REPL:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("while (<>) { if (/^(?:");
  for (int a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; ++a)
    for (int b = a; b <= 'z'; ++b)
      for (int c = b; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
        for (int d = c; d <= 'y'; ++d)
          printf("%c%c%c%c[%c-z]|", a, b, c, d, d);
        printf("%c%c%czz", a, b, c);
        if (a != 'z' || b != 'z' || c != 'z') printf("|\n");
      }
  printf(")$/x) { print \"Match!\\n\" } else { print \"No match.\\n\" }}\n");
  return 0;
}
```

And now:

```
$ gcc r.c
$ ./a.out > foo.pl
$ cat > data.txt
aaaaa
abcde
xxyyz
ghost
chips
demos
abCde
xxyyzz
hgost
chps
^D
$ perl foo.pl < data.txt
Match!
Match!
Match!
Match!
Match!
Match!
No match.
No match.
No match.
No match.
```

The regex is only 220Kb or so ;-)

Comment: Aargh. Your regex broke Rubular (can't make a permalink). :-) Yep, it's [219 KB raw](https://pastebin.com/raw/CvANkCM8) and works!

Comment: Thanks for this. Using the raw regex text (from @Jedi paste bin) I put it through this [ternary tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg) and made a full blown regex trie. That reduced the size quite a bit (160k [compressed](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/__Misc/Series_a-z_Ascending_5_letters_Compressed.txt), 840k [formatted](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/__Misc/Series_a-z_Ascending_5_letters_Formatted.txt)). Here is a [Python test](http://rextester.com/CECLB89681).

Comment: Also, I generated the full 142,506 possible strings, then used the full trie regex I made to test the performance: `Regex1: <omitted>
    Options:  < none >
    Completed iterations:   1  /  1     ( x 1 )
    Matches found per iteration:   142506
    Elapsed Time:    0.18 s,   178.87 ms,   178871 µs`